# How do I keep the shape of an UIELement while doing a Drag and Drop in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, uielement

I have 2 `StackPanel`s - one containing an `Ellipse` and the other one containing nothing.

I want to drag the `Ellipse` from one stack panel to the other. The actual drag & drop is already done and works fine, however I'd like to know how to keep that `Ellipse` shape at the tip of my mouse cursor.

Even a Windows Forms example would be nice, I'll be able to adapt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add your drag adorner during the drag.  I've seen this done a few different ways, but a quick search leads to [this behavior](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/en-us/DragDropBehavior), which has as nice a pattern as I've seen.  A representative sample is:

```
    void itemsControl_PreviewDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        ItemsControl itemsControl = (ItemsControl)sender;
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(ItemType))
        {
            object data = e.Data.GetData(ItemType);
            InitializeDragAdorner(itemsControl, data, e.GetPosition(itemsControl));
            InitializeInsertAdorner(itemsControl, e);
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

They wrap up all the presentation of the drag adornment nicely in the `DragAdorner` class.  (I wish I'd done mine this way, actually)

I've also seen tricks with building the adornment out of a Visual Brush of the originally dragged element, but I think I like this approach best so far.

BTW: After approaching this a few different times, I highly recommend wrapping your drag and drop code up into a behavior.  Otherwise you wind up with it all over the place.  Getting the commanding right with MVVM can be quite tricky, but it's worth it, IMHO.